# I have a fillable pdf so how can I use it in react-native so that user can fill the forms

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a local pdf with fillable input forms and hence when opened in chrome's pdf it can be filled so how can we use react-native to fill the pdf.

Comment: I need it for mobile application as I am using react-native.